# Effect of using .prototype to declare a method?

Tags: javascript, object

See this example of a simple circle class with a prototype area method:

```
var Circle = function(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}

Circle.prototype.area = function() {
   return Math.PI*this.radius*this.radius;
}
```

What's the difference between the area function declared above and if it were just declared as a public method of the Circle in the first place? Either way, individual instances of circle have their own area, do they not? What's the difference??

```
this.area = function(){return Math.PI*this.radius*this.radius;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.area = function(){}` creates a *new* function and assigns it to the `area` property of `this`.  `Circle.prototype.area = function(){}` creates a function *once*, and assigns it to the `prototype` of objects created by the `Circle()` constructor.

Answer (score 3):

If you declare it within the constructor then every instance of `Circle` will have a separate copy of the function. This would just be a waste of resources, since all `Circle` objects could share the same code.

Comment: But I have also read that prototype properties don't have access to local variables-- this seems like an unfavorable combination. Is there a way to create a single method which *does* have access to local variables?

Comment: What do you mean by "local variables"?

Comment: In the duplicate question, the top answerer says "On the flip side of the coin, public methods have access to "private" variables, which isn't possible with inherited methods."

Comment: (I meant private, not local. Slip of the keyboard.)

Comment: @Aerovistae: "Local" is the correct term, not "private". Your example has no local variables in the constructor, so non-issue in that case.

Comment: By definition, no, since the scope of a JS function is lexically-defined. What he calls "private" variables are closed-over objects in the constructor, so a function that closes over them has to have access to them when the function is created.

Comment: That said plenty of very powerful languages (e.g. Python) do not make a habit of using "private" object members and just assign a property with an underscore prefix if they don't want a user to rely on it. No reason you couldn't do that instead.

Comment: OH are we talking about NON `this.x` variables?? As in, just plain old `var x= 5`, that sort of thing? Of course `prototype` wouldn't have access to any of those declared inside the initial function definition...

Comment: @Aerovistae - A lot (perhaps all) of this private variables access can be done with closures without giving up the benefits of defining instance methods in the constructor prototype. For instance, you can wrap the entire definition in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Answer (score 1):

`this` points to an instance of the function object, `.prototype` "points" to the function constructor that created the instances ( there is only one ).  Normally in classical inheritance a class creates object instances.  But in JavaScript because there are no classes a "function constructor" creates object instances.  Sometimes I hear people say "function object" as well.